# django previous month view, url for the previous month

Tags: python, django

im following the instructions here on the previous month view (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/) however it doesnt quite show how to do the url for the previous month.

On my index page i have the current events displayed in a particular format, then i have links at the top for upcoming and previous, the previous goes to a different template, of which im trying to load the month previous view.

As you can see the error is with the url, im not quite sure how i get the url in there correctly

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

from maintenance.views import EventMonthArchiveView


app_name = 'maintenance'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^previous/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/$',
        EventMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'),
        name="previous"),
    url(r'^upcoming$', views.upcoming, name='upcoming'),
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta, time
from django.views.generic.dates import MonthArchiveView

from .models import Maintenance
from .models import MaintenanceType
from .models import ServiceType

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    today = date.today()
    ObjMaintenance = Maintenance.objects.filter(StartTime__gt=today)

    return render(request, 'maintenance/index.html', {'Maintenance': ObjMaintenance,})

class EventMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    queryset = Maintenance.objects.all()
    date_field = "StartTime"
    allow_future = False
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <h2>IT Maintenance Schedule</h2>
        <div id="page-content-header">
            <div class="float-left">
                <a href="{% url 'maintenance:previous|date:"F Y"' %}"><< Previous Maintenance</a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-middle">
                <a href="{% url 'maintenance:index' %}">Maintenance Today</a>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <a href="{% url 'maintenance:upcoming' %}">Upcoming Maintenance >></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div id='content-body'>
            {% for event in Maintenance %}
            <p>
                {{ event.Title }}
            </p>
            {% empty %}
            <p>There is no maintenance scheulded for today.</p>
            {% endfor%}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

error

```
u'previous|date' is not a registered namespace inside 'maintenance'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://it.wrenkitchens.com/maintenance/
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
u'previous|date' is not a registered namespace inside 'maintenance'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. The immediate error is because you have the filter inside the quotes, but it wouldn't work even if you took it out; what date are you trying to format?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just wanted to send whatever the last month is dynamically to the view

Comment: You mean the last month from today's date?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes exactly, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider how you would use the url tag for a particular month, say April 2016:

```
{% url 'maintenance:previous' '2016' '04' %}
```

If you want to make this dynamic, then you need a context variable that contains the previous month. If you are using the [`MonthArchiveView][1], then Django includes`previous_month`in the template context for you. This is a Python date representing the first day of the previous month. You then use the`date` filter to convert that datetime to the year and month string.

```
{% url 'maintenance:previous' previous_month|date:"Y" previous_month|date:"m" %}
```

Note that I've used 'm', not 'F', because you use '04', not 'April' in the urls.

Finally, if you want this link on the index view, you'll need to pass `previous_month` to the template context yourself. You can get the last day of the previous month by getting the first day of the current month, then subtracting one day. Since you only need the

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def index(request):
    today = date.today()
    previous_month = (today.replace(day=1) - timedelta(1)).replace(day=1)
    ObjMaintenance = Maintenance.objects.filter(StartTime__gt=today)

    return render(request, 'maintenance/index.html', {
        'Maintenance': ObjMaintenance,
        'previous_month': previous_month,
    })
```

Comment: i have the view under previous, not index. but the url is on the index template if that makes a difference? i get the same error each time "Reverse for 'previous' with arguments '(u'', u'')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. The `u'',` suggests that `previous_month` has not been included in the template correctly. Which view is rendering the index template?

Comment: ahhh now, i understand, the page loads and url now works :) thanks